# How to ignore files using git-gui (tcl-tk) application?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-gui

I'm using the `git-gui` interface to manage my `git` project. Despite being ugly –`tcl-tk`– it's one of the most complete interface out there.

However, I can't find **how to ignore files from this interface ?**

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. You can put a ticket or use another tool or the command line

Comment: The only thing I found related to it is this ticket https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=115 It can means nothing but if there is no way to edit `.gitignore` i guess it is not possible to do it with the ui either. Any way there is no option in the menus and also no related info on the internet

Answer (score 33, accepted):

the pragmatic way is, to add this to your `git` configuration:

```
git config --global guitool."Add to .gitignore".cmd $'echo "\n$FILENAME" >> .gitignore & git add .gitignore'
git config --global guitool."Add to .gitignore".needsfile yes
git config --global guitool."Add to .gitignore".confirm yes
```

#### Usage

After that, you can use it under `Tools > Ignore selected file` in your `git gui`.
Select a file you want to ignore under `Unstaged Changes -> Tools/ignore selected file`

[image: Ignore file with git-gui]

Comment: What is the value that I should put for $FILENAME, but still after running command 2nd and 3rd, I can see 'Ignore' option under Tools

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!

Comment: Good trick but simple. It can't handle ignoring a prefix or a folder.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean ignore them forever, then add a `.gitignore` file in the root of your directory (where the `.git` folder is). List the files or file types separated by a new line like so:

```
*.pyc
venv
.metadata
```

If you mean ignoring it temporarily, you can do the `.gitignore` step or just stage the files you want to commit individually.

Comment: I'm looking for the GUI equivalent of that

Answer (score 2):

If you set it in your .gitconfig file, the GUI will comply.

Add this to your `.gitconfig` (should be located under c:\users\USERNAME)

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

Then create a file `c:\users\USERNAME\.gitignore`

and add the ignore files to that.

Comment: Looking for a GUI process, I'm aware of the .gitignore file

Answer (score -2):

You can try to add all the files first. After that go to git gui, choose those files you want to ignore in "Staged Changes" and press Ctrl-U.